# Complex value for arcsin(π)?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Was bored and I just started finding a complex solution for $\arcsin(π)$, and im not sure if the solution I got is correct.
I started with euler's formula, $e^{iθ} = \cos(θ) + i \sin(θ)$, and then replace theta with $\arcsin(θ)$, so we get:

$e^{i \cdot \arcsin(π)} = \cos(\arcsin(π))+ i \sin(\arcsin(π))$

Next step I did was to factor it, by having the formula: $\cos(\arcsin(θ)) = \sqrt{1-θ^2}$, and the formula: $\sin(\arcsin(θ)) = θ$, and then I got:

$e^{i \cdot \arcsin(π)} = \sqrt{1-π^2} + iπ$

Next step, I took the natural logarithm of both sides, then got:

$i \arcsin(π) = \ln(\sqrt{1-π^2} + iπ)$

About next step, I tried to first simplify that natural logarithm in the second side of equation, by turning $\sqrt{1-π^2}$ into $\sqrt{-(π^2 - 1)}$, which we can get it to: $i \sqrt{π^2 - 1}$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit. Hence, my next equation was:

$i \arcsin(π) = \ln(i \sqrt{π^2-1} + iπ)$

And then, factor the input of natural logarithm:

$i \arcsin(π) = \ln(i(\sqrt{π^2-1} + π))$

Next, I applied to my natural logarithm, the following formula: $\ln(xy) = \ln(x) + \ln(y)$, thus:

$i \arcsin(π) = \ln(i) + \ln(\sqrt{π^2-1} + π)$

Last step, divide both sides by $i$:

$\arcsin(π) = \frac{\ln(i) + \ln(\sqrt{π^2-1} + π)}{i}$

Since that answer wasn't that satisfying for me, I approximated it, thus:

$\arcsin(π) = \frac{1.81152627 + 1.57079633 i}{i}$

And here is last thing I do in here, it is simplifying it:

$\arcsin(π) = 1.57079633 - 1.81152627 i$

Is there anything wrong I did, and If so, what was the mistake I have done here? Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Yes, $1.570796327 - 1.811526273 i$ is one of the values of $\arcsin(\pi)$.  It is the principal value chosen by Maple.

Answer (score 2):

another possible way:
$$y=\arcsin(\pi)\Rightarrow \pi=\sin(y)$$
$$\pi=\frac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{2i}$$
$$e^{iy}-e^{-iy}=2i\pi$$
$$e^{2iy}-2i\pi e^{iy}-1=0$$
now you have a quadratic which you can solve for a quadratic $y$, and take into account the periodicity with $\Re(y)$.